# Showing Country/state data in jVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mapping, jvectormap

I must admit that I am new to jQuery and JS but I really like the cool things you can do with jVectorMap. But so far I failed to add one thing: On mouseover/hover normally the name of the state or country is shown. Is it possible to add the related data (e.g. the GDP value)? 
And / or is it possible to add a legend with the color values of the countries/states?
Thanks a lot!
Claus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [data visualization example](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/#data_visualization_with_jvectormap) you could add in a callback function to show the related figure for the chosen state code. So if your data looked like:

```
var gdpData = {"ca":34.56 ...}
```

Then you could do something like...

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    colors: colors,
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    onLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
       label.text(label.text() + " (" + gdpData[code] + ")");
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer -- it works perfectly. I decidec to change the jquery.vector-map.js on line 337 to 'map.label.text(mapData.pathes[code].name + (":") + gdpData[code]);'

Comment: No problem. I guess the benefit of using the callback functions is that you're not altering the core plugin code, but as long as it works!....